# SSAS / PowerBI RS. A measure in PBI to show Server Name, or a field in SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: powerbi, dax, m, ssas-tabular, power-bi-report-server

I have some PowerBI RS reports connected to clustered SSAS boxes (live connection). The report would point to the cluster server, one or the other SSAS box would be primary. Say Box 1 or box 2.

Is there measure I can create in PBI, or measure/calculated column/field in a SSAS Tabular model, which would show the server name?

Eg. SSAS server 1 or SSAS server 2.

Since I'm on a live connection, I'm limited to measures / DAX, which I suspect can't do what I'm looking for, so it may be more of an SSAS-Tabular question, but I thought I'd ask here.

There may also be the issue that it will just show the cluster name, say SSASCluster

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit hacky, but maybe add a new table to SSAS cube by using the technique described here: [https://www.decisivedata.net/blog/how-to-create-an-automated-data-dictionary-in-ssas-tabular](http://Sounds%20a%20bit%20hacky,%20but%20maybe%20add%20a%20new%20table%20to%20tabular%20cube%20by%20using%20the%20technique%20described%20https://www.decisivedata.net/blog/how-to-create-an-automated-data-dictionary-in-ssas-tabular) and fill it with current node name, maybe found somewhere in the DMVs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15. Then of course that table should be processed every once in a while in order to refresh the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't create measures in Power BI when using Live Connection to SSAS data source. So, the only option is to perform some workaround on the SSAS-Tabular model, as Gigga also suggested.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean calculated columns? You can create measures when using Live Connection, and I do all the time

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You can't create measures when using Live Connection to SSAS Multidimensional, but you can in Tabular. Yes, calculated columns can't be created in Tabular.